# Can't get value from Object key properly

Tags: javascript, object, key

I'm using a loop to import data from a TSV file.
When I use console.log(d) I'm getting objects that look like this:

Object {indic_ed,geo\time: "G07_1,AT", "2001 ": "69.3 ", "2002 ": "69.0 ", "2003 ": "69.4 ", "2004 ": "75.6 "…}

I did manage to get data from the years (like d["2001 "]), but I can't seem to get the value for idic_ed,geo\time, since that gives me an error.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the backslash in the string:

```
d["indic_ed,geo\\time"]
```

Comment: Nice one. Beat me to it by a few seconds.